# Combine these two IF statements into one?

Tags: bash, shell, logic

Any way to combine these two IF statements into one...

```
if [ -n "$(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep Shared | grep Yes)" ]; then 
    echo 1
fi
if [ -n "$(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep 'System Printer Sharing: Yes')" ]; then 
    echo 1
fi
```

Comment: That depends on what you want the result to be. Output 1 if both conditions are true? Either condition? Output a separate 1 for each condition that is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `||` short circuit evaluation in between:

```
if [ -n ... ] || [ -n ... ]; then ## Something; fi
```

`||` is treated as logical OR (and `&&` is logical AND).

In your case:

```
if [ -n "$(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep Shared | grep Yes)" ] || [ -n "$(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep 'System Printer Sharing: Yes')" ]; then 
    echo 1
fi
```

---

Just to note, if you use the bash keyword `[[`, then the following is valid too:

```
if [[ -n ... || -n ... ]]; then ## Something; fi
```

Comment: This solution is not correct IMHO, because your condition fires only, if both strings are present, while the code in the original posting fires, if at least one of the strings is present.

Comment: @user1934428 Seconded. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ -n $(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep Shared | grep Yes)$(system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | grep 'System Printer Sharing: Yes') ]] && echo 1
```

Note:

- You want to echo 1 if either one of the strings is non-empty or if the other one is non-empty. In this case, it is simpler to catenate the strings and look at the result: If the result is non-empty, at least one of the imput strings must be non-empty.
- There is no need to use an `if` statement in this case (although it is not forbidden).
- You don't need to quote the argument to `-s`, if you use `[[ ... ]]` for testing the string.
- When you grep for *Shared*, should it be allowed that the word *Yes* appears **before** the word *Shared* in the line? If not, it would be simpler to write `grep 'Shared.*Yes`.
- Since you are not interested in the actual output of the *grep* command, but only in the fact, that it matches, something like this would also work:

  ```
  {system_profiler SPPrintersDataType|grep -q 'Shared.*Yes} || {system_profiler SPPrintersDataType|grep -Fq  'System Printer Sharing: Yes'} && echo 1
  ```
- Finally, assuming that the system_profiler command produces the same output in both invocations, the code could be simplified to:

  ```
  {system_profiler SPPrintersDataType|grep -Eq 'Shared.*Yes|System Printer Sharing: Yes'} && echo 1
  ```

This basically says: *If there is a line in system_profiler which contains Shared...Yes OR a line containing System Printer Sharing Yes, then echo 1*. You need the -E in inorder to get the `|` to work in the regexp pattern.

Admittedly, all these suggestions mean that you get only one `1` being echoed, if the condition is fulfilled, while in your original solution, you get two `1` being echoed, if *both* conditions are fulfilled. Therefore, my solution is not *exactly* equivalent to yours. However, since you explicitly said that you wanted to *combine* the cases, I think this is acceptable.

Comment: OK, explanations added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the output of your `system_profiler` looks, so going a bit on guesswork here.  If the `Shared` and `Yes` are always in the same order within a line, you can grep for them together with

```
grep 'Shared.*Yes'
```

and you can grep for both of your expressions in one pass with

```
grep 'Shared.*Yes\|System Printer Sharing: Yes'
```

You can then write your command as

```
system_profiler SPPrintersDataType \
  | grep -q 'Shared.*Yes\|System Printer Sharing: Yes' \
    && echo 1
```

Note that we use `grep -q` to suppress output, as we're only interested in the return code.

Note also that if both of the strings are present, we only output one `1` - I'm guessing that's what you want, but I mention it as it is a difference from your script.